# Is there a way to automatically sign out of the desktop Microsoft Teams application when idle?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

The devices that are required to be signed out are Windows 11 devices, is there a way such as script to automatically sign out of Microsoft Teams for desktop?

This .bat was tried but did not work as expected.

```
taskkill /F /IM Teams.exe
;REM this kills all teams.exe processes

taskkill /F /IM msteams.exe
;REM this kills the msteams.exe process (this process is not always running)

rmdir "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin_cw5n1h2txyewy" /s /Q

;REM this deletes the stored "prior logged-in-username part"

del "C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftTeams_8wekyb3d8bbwe\*.*" /F /s /Q

;REM this deletes the stored "prior user-credentials part"
```

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: In what way was it "not expected"? How did you trigger this script? You know any script that indiscriminately kills processes like this is a bad idea. Since Teams is an instant messaging application it seems counter intuitive to stop it